# I am getting this error when running jar file on linux - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger

Tags: java, linux, log4j

I created a java project and when I run it from NetBeans it runs correctly and does what is supposed to but when I move it on the Linux server it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at arhivare.Arhivare.<clinit>(Arhivare.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

It has to to with log4j library which I included in the project (it runs in Netbeans). What am I missing ?

Comment: Can you show the code ? how you initialize your `Logger` ?

Comment: What's the command you use to run your application?

Answer (score -1):

```
 public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Arhivare.class);
```

This is how I initialize my Logger and the command to run the application is: 
java -jar ArhivareProd.jar

Comment: You should not add your additional comments as an answer to your question. Either update your original question or use comments.

Comment: With what did your remark help ?

Comment: Is this an *answer* or a *completion* of your *question*?